# Can't get ribbon to show with IsDlg=1 on Application Pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ribbon-control

I am using SharePoint 2013.

I am using a modal dialog with the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog method.

I also have a Ribbon in the custom application page.

This all worked in SharePoint 2010, but in 2013 it doesn't work.  The ribbon is no longer showing.

How can I resovle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SharePoint 2013 masterpage the elements that shouldn't be visible in the dialog mode (**IsDlg=1**) have the "s4-notdlg" CSS class applied.
To solve your problem you have the following options:

1. Dynamically (using jQuery for example) remove the **s4-notdlg** class form the div of the.Ribbon section
2. Use the open-source library [SharePoint 2013 Easy Ribbon API](http://easyribbon.codeplex.com/). We have tested this library with custom application pages, and it seems to satisfy all our needs.